# Session is expired after refreshing the page using SSL

Tags: php, session, ssl

Having troubles with my PHP website. When I use http protocol session works fine as it should be. When switch to https and log in to a page it shows no errors, still seems it's alright. But when I go to another page session is expired. And I can't get what possibly could be a reason. Google's chrome console is clear. Also no http content is loaded over my website. Maybe trouble appears because of wrong configured https certificate or else?

Comment: Is the "another page" on HTTPS too?

Comment: Yes, my https protocol is a global variable and it's always the same one protocol